# Flutter: Google sign in caused a black line running across screen

Tags: flutter, google-signin

I have my code as following for Google Sign in:

```
   // google sign in
   GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
      scopes: [
        'email',
      ],
    );
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
        await googleUser.authentication;

    // get firebase user
    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken, idToken: googleAuth.idToken);
    firebaseUser = (await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
```

After a user signs in successfully thru Google, I will see a solid thick black line running from top to bottom of the screen. I have attached two screenshots to prove it here. Any idea on getting rid of it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: post a screenshot showing the grey line

Comment: you can use the flutter inspector to see the widget tree and understand why it's happening