# Flutter Google sign in solid black line moving across the screen

Tags: flutter, user-interface, google-signin

I implemented Google sign-in with my Flutter application and everything works like a charm except the black solid line about 15 pixels in height and full-width that moves across the screen from top to bottom right after the successful sign-in takes place. Here is a GIF that demonstrates that. I recorded 3 seconds right after I chose from Google accounts on the device:

[image: bug demonstration]

How can I get rid of that line or that's 'expected' behavior? I couldn't find any information online about that except [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62970628/flutter-google-sign-in-caused-a-black-line-running-across-screen) that has never been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a know issue with several open threads. Please check the most recently active thread and there are some potential fix or workarounds given at the bottom that you may try : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48371

Potential Workaround url : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48371#issuecomment-629549018

Comment: That's what I've been looking for! I couldn't find it on Google. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

add that line:

```
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
```

change `styles.xml In android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml` and
`android/app/src/main/res/values-night/styles.xml` as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<!-- Theme applied to the Android Window while the process is starting when the OS's Dark Mode setting is on -->
<style name="LaunchTheme"parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
    <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
         the Flutter engine draws its first frame -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
</style>
<!-- Theme applied to the Android Window as soon as the process has started.
     This theme determines the color of the Android Window while your
     Flutter UI initializes, as well as behind your Flutter UI while its
     running.

     This Theme is only used starting with V2 of Flutter's Android embedding. -->
<style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
</style>
```